# require a parallel directives controller w/o creating a parent controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, controller

**Question:**
is it possible, to make a direct connection between two parallel directives w/o creating a factory, parent-directive or emit/broadcast but just a straight `require: 'directiveA'`

**Note:** *if i'm being silly with this request please tell me... I just like the readability of this idea and am curious if it is feasible?*

Here we go, I have two directives that are parallel to another.

**HTML:**

```
<div directive-a>
  <!-- 1. that also has a click event-->
  <div ng-click="updateStore('1234')">click to update store</div>
  <p>{{storeDataA}}</p>
</div>
<div directive-b>
  <!-- 2. this will display the updated storeID -->
  <p> {{newStoreDataB}}</p>
</div>
```

**JS:: directive-a**

```
angular.module('carouselApp')
.directive('directiveA',  function () {

    return {

        templateUrl: 'views/modal/directiveA.html',
        //note this require statement.
        require: 'directiveB',
        link: function (scope, el, attrs, ctrl) {
          scope.updateStore = function(storeID){ 
              scope.storeDataA = storeID;
              ctrl.updateStoreB(storeID) 
            };

        }});
```

**JS:: directive-b**

```
angular.module('carouselApp')
  .directive('directiveA',  function () {

    return {

        templateUrl: 'views/modal/directiveB.html',
        controller: function($scope){
         this.updateStoreB = function(storeID){
            $scope.storeB = storeID+"storeB";
          }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Why not using objects to connect directives? Like ng-model ="tst" connects to ng-repeat="obj in objs | filter:tst"...

Comment: This is a contrived example of what I'm really trying to do. Your idea maybe proper but could you post a better more complete answer?  because I dont really understand .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a good way to accomplish this "action at a distance". Without some sort of parent-child relationship, there isn't really a way for your directives to find each other (what would Angular do if you had two `directiveB`s?). Your best bet is probably to use a service to let these directives communicate. It won't change the HTML markup, and it will make it explicit that they have a co-dependency.

To answer your question explicitly: the `require` relationship is only between a directive and its ancestors.

Comment: Yeah I think I had the epiphany from the comment to pass a ng-model value through the view and watch it between directives. when the value changes trigger my function.